# How to show a modal without shifting the content to the left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

For a bootstrap modal. Is there a way to achieve both:

1. Avoid the background content behind the modal from being scrollable
2. When opening the modal, the background content should not shift to the right because of removed scrollbars

The best solution I have so far is:

```
.modal-open {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

But it has the problem that the background content is still scrollable when the modal is showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This works for me without any shift.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Will still relayout when scrollbars are removed for body as modal is opened.

Comment: But this still allows the content to be scrolled behind the modal... Do you know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

> How to show a modal without shifting the content to the left?

That bug is fixed in the upcoming Bootstrap v3.2.0 thanks to
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13103